# GTMSessionFetcher.framework: No such file or directory

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8

As soon as I install cocoapods, the error comes up. Before that there is no trace of the error.

Below is a screenshot of the error in the Debug console:
[Debug Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zv2Jy.jpg)

What I have tried:

1. Uninstalling and reinstalling cocoapods
2. uninstalling and reinstalling all pods
3. starting the project from scratch all over again
4. I am using the xcworkspace file, not the xcodeproj file
5. Updated all pods.
6. Deleted Derived data folder
7. did a clean and a computer restart after each of these steps.

Podfile: [PodfileText](https://justpaste.it/191e2)